# Oracle APEX v19.1 mailto link based on selections in form that are results of query

Tags: javascript, dynamic, apex, mailto

Objective:  Create a link (button or html) that will use values updated in form, based on the selection of list box.

Issue:  I have built the page and form that creates a "mailto:" URL constructed using values selected in the form, however I am unable to change the button value or the html  created by the first rendering of the page.  Meaning, even though I place the string (URL) into a hidden field with my dynamic action, the rendered URL does not update and the dynamic action click trigger seems to only use the original value, not the updated one. (btw: not writing the values to a table).

Is there a way to trigger a URL using current pValues?

I have successfully created a functional mailto url in the page form which I can see updated, however when I use dynamic action click to open URL is uses 'original' value, not the new value I have created by selections in the form.

When using the href option based on the pValue, and showing the region, it also uses only the original pValue, not the current one.  I tried refreshing the region as part of the dynamic action that populated the pValue, but that had no impact.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine your entire setup and the various elements involved. What you want however is simple to do. At its core, you want to do the following to achieve your objective:

- You have a page item (hidden or not) to hold the constructed link
- Your form updates the page item correctly
- You submit the page (using your button or something else)
- Add branch (Behavior type: URL Identified by Item (Redirect))